# Xpath having elements with and without prefixes in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces

Want to fetch the value at xpaths `/SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult/configInfo/equipment.PhysicalPort/description`
and

```
/SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult/deployer
```

From the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <SOAP:Header>
          <header xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
               <requestID>XXX</requestID>
          </header>
     </SOAP:Header>
     <SOAP:Body>
          <generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
               <deployer>deployer value</deployer>
               <synchronousDeploy>XXX</synchronousDeploy>
               <distinguishedName>XXX</distinguishedName>
               <includeChildren>XXX</includeChildren>
               <configInfo>
                    <equipment.PhysicalPort>
                         <actionMask>
                              <bit>XXX</bit>
                         </actionMask>
                         <administrativeState>XXX</administrativeState>
                         <loadBalanceAlgorithm>XXX</loadBalanceAlgorithm>
                         <description>XXX</description>
                    </equipment.PhysicalPort>
               </configInfo>
          </generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult>
     </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I cannot change the Xml or the xpath so need to come up with a logic to deal with it.
Kindly let me know how to handle it.

Comment: i hard understand about namespace, maybe such consrtruction helps `//*[local-name() = "description"]`

Comment: Yes, it helps but I cannot change the Xpath. Looking for a solution in which I can set the namespace context in a way that it works.

Comment: Show us the Java code you're using, and tell what result it gives. Then we can help you fix it. You need to register the SOAP namespace prefix to the namespace URI `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`, and use that when you execute the XPath query.

Comment: and you need to set the namespace `xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"` also in Java

Comment: Good point, @MarkVeenstra. How you (the OP) do that depends on what XPath API you're using in Java.